# Synology disk station as local dropbox alternative

Tags: dropbox, synology, owncloud, synology-diskstation

Does anyone know if and how I could use my Synology disk-station as a kind of local dropbox server, i.e. I have a folder that is always synchronized locally between the NAS and the respective computers in my network (linux and windows).

I've heard about ownCloud but it's not among the synology package center. (I'm not super hot on installing unsafe packages)

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is an opinion question. You need one of the many sync products (I use SyncBack Pro) and set up secure access to you NAS from remote locations.

Comment: Dont want to access it from remote locations only within my local network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. There is already a package for that exact purpose. It's called "Synology Drive". I could install it from the package manager. Via web interface you can download the individual clients for each machine afterwards